# Is there a way to connect to a specific WiFi network in dotnet Maui?

Tags: c#, maui, maui-android, maui-ios

I am creating an app which needs to connect to a device that is running a WiFi hotspot. However, to make this more user-friendly, I would like to make the app connect to the hotspot on the user's behalf.

For example, when the app starts, the user presses "connect", and a spinner appears while the app connects to the network. The SSID and passphrase may not be saved already on the phone.

I would also like there to be a method that the user can press a "Disconnect" button to return to the previous network.

I would like this method to be as Cross-Platform as possible. Especially Android and iOS.

Many thanks in advance if you can shed any light on how I might achieve this!

(I could not find anything online with a suitable method of achieving this - it seemed there were no APIs).

Answer (score 0):

MAUI is a cross-platform UI framework and it exposes all of the potential OS SDKs through C#. So you may need to use the corresponding native APIs for different platforms to connect to a specifical WIFI network.

For more information, you can refer to the listed docs below:

[WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager)

[WifiNetworkSpecifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSpecifier) for Android 10+.

[NEHotspotConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration) for iOS.

[Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0). Invoke the native APIs on MAUI.

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.